# Using local MathJax repository with Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, mathjax

I am trying to develop my first Chrome extension to properly render equations in markdown. However after the page is loaded I see the following error in the console and my equations are not getting rendered properly:

> ERROR: MathJax.js:19 GET file:///extensions/MathMenu.js?rev=2.6.1 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

My extension has the following structure.

- vendor

  - MathJax-2.6/
  - config
  - extensions
  - ...
- manifest.json
- template.html
- ...

and my manifest file looks like this

```js
{
    "name": "extensionizr template",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "This extension was created with the awesome extensionizr.com",
    "homepage_url": "http://extensionizr.com",
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/icon16.png",
        "48": "icons/icon48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon128.png"
    },
    "default_locale": "en",
    "page_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png",
        "default_title": "page action demo",
        "default_popup": "src/page_action/page_action.html"
    },
    "permissions": [],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "template.html",
        "fonts/*.*"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["file:///*/*.md*", "http://*/*.md*"],
        "css": [
            "css/bootstrap.css",
            "css/flashcards.css"
        ],
        "js": [
            "js/jquery.js",
            "js/bootstrap.min.js",
            "js/list.js", "js/list.fuzzysearch.js", "js/list.pagination.js",
            "js/showdown.init.js", "vendor/showdown-1.4.2/dist/showdown.js",
            "vendor/showdown-1.4.2/dist/showdown-prettify.min.js",
            "vendor/MathJax-2.6/MathJax.js",
            "vendor/MathJax-2.6/extensions/tex2jax.js",
            "js/flashcards.js"
        ]
    }]
}
```

Is there anything I am missing in the manifest file?

Comment: The error says MathJax.js couldn't load MathMenu.js. Look at the specified code line (19). It's probable the file is injected via `<script>` element or downloaded via AJAX. In this particular case you need to declare that file(s) in ["web_accessible_resources"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Comment: MathJax has many components beyond MathJax.js and tex2jax. You need to declare them all, depending on your configuration needs. You might want to look at https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-grunt-cleaner or https://github.com/pkra/MathJax-single-file for help in minimizing your installation of Mathjax.